# java get the number of array values

Tags: java, arrays

I already have the following code

```
public class Qn3
{
    static BigDecimal[] accbal= new BigDecimal[20];
    private static Integer[] accnums = new Integer[5];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int count;
         accnums = {1,2} //i cant add this line of code as well, what is wrong?
         while(accnums.length < 5)
         {
              count = accnums.number_of_filled_up_indexes 
               //this is not actual code i know 
           //do this as the number of values in the array are less than 5
           break;
          }
           //do this as number of values in the array are more than 5
    }
}
```

**I must use this code there is no changing this is a requirment, so please dont suggest to use arraylist and such (i am aware of other array types and methods)**

The problem is that as I have already declared that `accnums` must contain only 5 values, that is predefined.

I am trying to perform a check whether the ones that are not null and if all are null. To do this I have tried this but this is giving me 5 p(pre-defined integer array value not what I want).

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.. See MadProgrammer's answer - just use a for loop and keep your count in a variable that you can increment for each index that is not null. The count at the end will be the total number of non-null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count = 0;
    accnums = new Integer[] {1,2,null,null,null};
    for (int index = 0; index < accnums.length; index++) 
    {
        if(accnums[index] != null)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("You have used " + count + " slots);

}
```

Comment: `accnums.length - Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(accnums), null)`

Comment: PS `accnums` should be `new Integer[5] { 1, 2, null, null, null }`

Comment: @veer firstly, weren't allowed to `List`s :P, secondly <duh> - cheers

Comment: No problem dude! I figured we could use `Arrays.asList`, just not replace the type of `accnums` :-)

Comment: @veer that's just my take on the requirements, reality may be different ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
accnums[0] = new Integer(1);
accnums[1] = new Integer(2);
```

**Both the below will work if done during Declaration and Initializing time of and array.**

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
Integer[] arr = {1,2,3}
```

But when you just declare the array as

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[3]; // Still array holds no Object Reference Variable
```

then later initialize it this way...

```
arr = new Integer{1,2,3,};  // At this time it hold the ORV
```

**Array are always initialized whether used at class or method scope**, so for an int array all the values will be set to default as 0, and for `Integer` it will be `null`, as its an `Wrapper object`.

**Eg:**

```
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];

    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;

    System.out.println(arr.length);

    for (Integer i : arr){

        if (i!=null){

            count++;

      }



    }

    System.out.println("Total Index with Non Null Count :"+count);
```

}

Comment: yes tks that adds the value to the Integer array. but still my main question which is to check how many are filled up in the Integer array. tks

Answer (score 0):

```
accnums[0] = 1;
accnums[1] = 2;
final int count = accnums.length
    - Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(accnums), null);
System.out.println("You have used " + count + " slots");
```

or, if you really must do it manually...

```
int count;
for (final Integer val : accnums) {
  if (val != null) {
    ++count;
  }
}
```